# UITableView Separator line disappears when cell is inserted at first position and bottom cell is selected

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have code as follows:

```
#import "TestTableViewController.h"

@interface TestTableViewController ()
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSMutableArray *testDataArray;
@end

@implementation TestTableViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  self.testDataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
  for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
    [self.testDataArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"TestString - %@",@(i)]];
  }
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
  return self.testDataArray.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"testCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
  cell.textLabel.text = [self.testDataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
  return cell;
}

- (IBAction)insertNewElement:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender
{
  [self.testDataArray insertObject:@"AAAAAA" atIndex:0];
  [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:0 inSection:0]]
                        withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
}
```

As you see code is very simple.
Storyboard is also standard:

[image]

But when I select third cell and insert new cell this happen (Newly inserted cell is without separator line):

[image]

I found one solution, but there is a problem with it.First it uses Private API, and second I'm not sure that this is good practice to do:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
  [super layoutSubviews];

  for (UIView *subview in self.contentView.superview.subviews) {
    if ([NSStringFromClass(subview.class) hasSuffix:@"SeparatorView"]) {
      subview.hidden = NO;
    }
  }
}
```

Is it possible, that this is bug in Apple?

Comment: Have you tried same thing in real device, May be this is simulator issue,

Comment: Screenshot is from real device :)

Comment: I had similar problem and it had to do with cell selection. Try deselecting cell before adding the new one. Or is that not an option?

Comment: I've seen this with deselecting, but unfortunately cell have to stay selected.This is very simplified version of my app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to make little bit change in you simplified version of application with method implementation like,

```
- (IBAction)insertNewElement:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender
{
    //Update 1:
    [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:selectedrow inSection:0] animated:NO];
    [self.testDataArray insertObject:@"AAAAAA" atIndex:0];
    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:0 inSection:0]]
                      withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    [self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:selectedrow+1 inSection:0] animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
} //selectedrow define in your .m file as NSInteger.
```

May this help you!!

Comment: This works actually.Thanks @Viral Savaj  .But thing I don't like is reloadData method calling.This can cause problem with performance.

Comment: You can deselect row, just like selecting it after newly added row, instead of full reload data.

Comment: @Foriger, take a look at Update 1 line.

Comment: That works. Thanks a lot @Viral Savaj. I'm just unhappy about this implementation.It is very ugly to select and deselecting for just one hidden view. If there is no better answer  in some time I will accept this answer in 30 minutes.Big THANK YOU one more time.

Answer (score 1):

Building on the other answers I would use begin and endUpdates instead

```
- (IBAction)insertNewElement:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender
{
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    [self.testDataArray insertObject:@"AAAAAA" atIndex:0];
    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:0 inSection:0]]
                      withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    [self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:selectedrow+1 inSection:0] animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}
```

[https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/beginUpdates](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/index.html%23//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/beginUpdates)